# Create a dir on scratch with same name as in pwd directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

HI I try to simplify my problem,

I'm trying to write a bash script, which can take the actual directory name (just like you get by statement "basename" ) and create a same directory on scratch.

```
#!/bin/bash
#variables
name_on_scratch= "basename" "$PWD"
echo $name_on_scratch
home=`pwd`
workdir=/gpfs/scratch/$USER/$name_on_scratch/

rm -rf $workdir 2>/dev/null # delete if exist
#make a dir on scratch
mkdir $workdir


echo $workdir
echo $name_on_scratch
```

The problem is that I getting an error meassage:

```
mkdir: cannot create /gpfs/scratch/upolpnam//.
/gpfs/scratch/upolpnam//: File exists
/gpfs/scratch/upolpnam//
```

Now I'm little stuck. Does anybody know how to arround this.

Thank you for any suggestion

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment

```
name_on_scratch= "basename" "$PWD"
```

is improperly formed: `basename` is a command, so you need *command substitution* using either backticks or `$(...)` syntax. Also it can't have space around the `=` operator:

`name_on_scratch="$(basename "$PWD")"`

Comment: Thank you so much, for your answer and sollution. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that $jobid has a value which can be used as a directory name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Unfortunatelly I'm doing something else wrong. I have edit my quistion to simpler problem, and maybe now it is more clear and straithforward to users, what I'm trying to obtain. 
Thank you again